# Bug in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm working on a cogs that can make my bot work as a modmail. So far, here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

class Modmail(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        empty_array = []
        modmail_channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.get_all_channels(), name="modmail")

        if message.author == message.user:
            return
        if str(message.channel.type) == "private":
            if message.attachments != empty_array:
                files = message.attachments
                await modmail_channel.send("<@" + message.author.id + ">: ")

                for file in files:
                    await modmail_channel.send(file.url)
            else:
                await modmail_channel.send("<@" + str(message.author.id) + ">: " + message.content)

        elif str(message.channel) == "modmail" and message.content.startswith("<"):
            member_object = message.mentions[0]
            if message.attachments != empty_array:
                files = message.attachments
                await member_object.send("**[MOD]** " + "**" + message.author.display_name + "**: ")

                for file in files:
                    await member_object.send(file.url)
            else:
                index = message.content.index(" ")
                string = message.content
                mod_message = string[index:]
                await member_object.send("**[MOD]** " + "**" + message.author.display_name + "**: " + mod_message)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Modmail(bot))
```

So the problem is, when I run it, I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Blue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Blue\Documents\Project\Articuno (Canary)\automod.py", line 39, in on_message
    channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name="║logs")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channels'
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Blue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Blue\Documents\Project\Articuno (Canary)\modmail.py", line 14, in on_message
    modmail_channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.get_all_channels(), name="modmail")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_all_channels'
```

What should I fix this? Because as far as I know, message and guild can't work together. But if I do message.get_all_channels(), it will have another error!

Comment: A message won't have a guild if it's a DM message. Is someone DMing your bot?

Comment: When I run and DM the BOT, it show up that error. And I was the only one who DMed the BOT

Comment: As I said, direct messages do not have guilds. What do you expect `message.guild` to be in that case?

Comment: Well, if I only have ``message.get_all_channel``, I will have this error:
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Blue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Blue\Documents\Project\Articuno (Canary)\modmail.py", line 13, in on_message
    modmail_channel = discord.utils.get(message.get_all_channels(), name="modmail")
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'get_all_channels'

Comment: You're missing the point. The message is received via DM. For all Discord knows, your bot could be running on a hundred servers at once. *Which* server do you expect to get all of the channels for? There's no way for Discord or for the bot to know that, since the message didn't *come* from a server in the first place.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well yeah, you have a point